# Can not navigate outside an application

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-oauth2-oidc

I have an auth service that takes care of some auth errors by redirecting to identity server.
I have tried to do this by `window.location.href = environment.authCodeFlowIssuer;`, but I got an error:
`Refused to frame 'http://localhost:5005/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".`
and no redirection occures.
I have no idea by now why this does not work.
If I fire an assignment to `window.location.href` from dev tools command line, then it works.
I will appreciate any help and tips on what is goning on here or how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

It was because of iframe related to silent refresh.
`window.top.location.href = environment.authCodeFlowIssuer;` - that works fine